# Show that there is a k dimensional subspace E such that....

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, invariant-subspace

I am working on studying for an exam. I was looking at this old problem and was wondering if someone could help me out.

[image]

So far I think I can say that since k eigenvalues with non-positive real part then there are k generalized eigenvectors that span a stable space E. I am having a hard time with how to continue this problem though. Any help would be much appreciated for part a and b.

Comment: A hint for (a): If $AE\subset E$ then $e^{tA}E\subset E$ for any $t\ge0$ (indeed, for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Thank you... Do you know where I could read about this more? I am still struggling with it. Thanks

Comment: For example, C. Chicone [Ordinary Differential Equations with Applications](https://books.google.com/books/about/Ordinary_Differential_Equations_with_App.html?id=yfY2uGROVrUC&redir_esc=y), pp. 154-179. In particular, regarding (b) an application of Theorem 2.61 on pp. 174-175 to the restriction of $-A$ to a suitable invariant subspace should be helpful.

Comment: @user539887 Thank you! I will look at that for sure. I appreciate it

Comment: @user539887 would I want to use a jordan form argument on this problem? To show that the stable space is of the form $|x(t)|\leq |e^{tA}|\leq ce^{-\mu t}|x_0|$ for the space spanned by the real(lambda) $\leq$0? And similarly for part b, to show that the eigenvalues greater than 0 real part will cause the $e^{At}$ to blow up?

Comment: Chicone's proof just uses a Jordan form argument (look at his Proposition 2.37).